# Create custom select query in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This might be a weird question (and maybe not possible), but how do I create a select statement in oracle to select customs strings ?

For example, we can use the following:

```
SELECT  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
FROM    DUAL
```

and it will select a table with 5 columns, with values 1 to 5 respectively. I tried selecting strings, but it won't work, since dual has a column of type `VARCHAR2(1)`...

I want to create a table with column names (for example, `apples`, `bananas`, `oranges`) and then pivot it to have one column `column_name` ad every row representing one of my `fruits` and then iterate to do my operations.

Note that I do not want to create a table nor a view, this data will only be used in this query, and it's not available elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select 'apples' as colname from dual union all
select 'bananas' as colname from dual union all
select 'oranges' as colname from dual ;
```

You can put this logic into a CTE or subquery.